# Lighting in MRI

Tags: ac

Lighting in Magnetic Resonance Imaging Scan Rooms must be DC lighting.
Within the DC lighting fixtures, DC light bulbs must be used.
AC current of any kind is manifested as noise on our images and interferes with the Magnetic field operation.
MRI scanners operate on 64MHZ.

I am having trouble replacing light bulbs in these fixtures which are ceiling cans.  My engineering department tells me there are no differences in power source or filament between AC and DC bulbs. All incandescent bulbs are the same.

I believe this is not correct as far as MRI.  I believe it has to do with the fact that AC bulbs,  operate around 60 MHZ. Also, that the direction across the filament itself creates enough vibrations to cause noisy images.

LED lighting is not to be used, specifically CFLs, due to the noise it produces.

Comment: Your AC mains frequency is 60Hz, not 60MHz. Incandescent light bulbs are really just resistors which get very hot - they don't really 'care' very much if you're providing them with AC or DC. LEDs and CFLs are very much *not* the same thing and the 'noise' produced by one is very different to the other. But aside from all that, what is your actual question?

Comment: Also, CFL's are not LED's

Comment: If you were really worried about light bulbs causing interference to the scan use light pipes  and have the light sources well away from equipment.

Comment: Incandescent bulbs of any type produce no noise when driven with a DC voltage, also, LEDs could be driven by DC voltages and not produce any noise. CFLs are really just a different form of the fluorescent tubes of old driven at higher frequencies. They produce noise since their operation is based on a plasma.

Comment: What is the DC voltage supply to the lights? i.e. are the bulbs rated at say 240, 120, 48, 24 or 12 V?

Answer (score 7):

Your engineering department is right.

Old incandescent bulbs don't care whether they are driven with AC or DC.  They light according to the RMS voltage applied to them.  120 V RMS AC and 120 V DC will cause the filament to get to the same temperature, which causes it to emit the same light.

Answer (score 7):

MRI service tech here.
Don't mean to Necro but see a lot of calls about noise that ends up being lighting.
Some pointers:
If it's set up for DC, use like DC replacements.
This isolates the rectification to outside the room, for good reason. Also, it's what your system and install was designed for.
Incandescent bulbs are fine, until they blow.
Then, one of two things happen.
1) someone tosses in a great value led bulb in and the cheap half wave rectifier emits terrible RF noise.
2) the bulb blows and goes unchanged. Now you have a tiny little antenna.  If your room has any RF leaks, here we go.
Most modern(last 10 years) MRs recommend/require isolated external DC supplies, for good reason.

Example, I recently went to a site with a newish mobile system. GE 23x. Noise issues. The SNR of the images was over 4x higher with the lights on because the guys who built the mobile installed residential LED can lights.  It doesn't matter what frequency the mains are or what freq/Tesla the system is. Noise is noise and harmonics are harmonics.
Stick with the OEM recommendations on anything dealing with external power.  You don't have to buy it from them, but follow them.

Answer (score 5):

Another MRI service tech here. The reason they use Direct Current to power incandescent lights in MRI scan rooms is because the strong magnetic field would cause the filaments to vibrate at the 60 Hz line frequency. The filaments don't last long while vibrating like that. The lights closest to the magnet are affected the most. The line voltage must be rectified and filtered to minimize vibration and get maximum incandescent bulb life. These rectifiers and filters are installed outside the scan room, and the DC power is fed into the room via RF filters. Your engineering dept. is correct. There are no special incandescent bulbs for DC power.  Search for "traffic signal lamp" for some long life bulbs. Some are supposed to last 8,000 hours.

A single high brightness LED runs at about 3 volts. A typical light designed for use in a standard US fixture has about 10 LEDs wired in series inside. These lights must have a circuit inside to drop the 120 V line voltage down to about 30 V to drive the string of LEDs. This inverter circuit runs at 25 kHz to 300 kHz depending on design choices and varies with incoming line voltage. Because this inverter and it's harmonics are inside the scan room, they are often the source of noise interfering with MRI imaging.

There are LED fixtures designed for use inside MRI scan rooms. These are typically provided or specified by the manufacturer of the RF room shielding. To prevent generating interference, the power supply and filtering for MRI safe LED lighting is outside the scan room and pure DC of the desired voltage is fed into the room.

Answer (score 1):

AC power in the North America is 60 Hz, not MHZ. Incandescent bulbs require the same voltage whether they are powered with 50 Hz, 60 Hz or DC. AC voltages are designated as RMS. RMS measurement method provides effects equivalent to the same voltage and current values of DC with respect to circuits that are only resistive without significant inductance or capacitance. So DC of the same voltage works the same as AC as far as heating elements and incandescent lighting filaments are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

What DC voltages are available to power the lighting?

It may be true that AC powered LED light bulbs create noise, most dimmable LED lighting will create noise. The LED strips with only LEDs and no chips on them do not generate any noise.

Technically the difference is a switching regulator vs a linear regulator or no regulator. Switching generates noise where a linear regulator or resistor do not generate any noise.

A 120 VDC, required to light an incandescent bulb, is not a popular power supply.  If you plan on using a DC power supply, a switching power supply will  generate noise. You will need a linear supply and a 48-60 volt power supply and LED fixture would be much more efficient.

Electrical safety and building codes will be an issue with any DC voltage over 50-60 volts.

The choice of which direction to take would be based on what DC voltages are available.

If none are available, then LED lighting is the best approach.